# Aligning links to the bottom of the navbar

Tags: html, hyperlink, positioning, navbar

I am having difficulties making the links sit on the bottom of the navbar as intended. Ive attempted every trick i could think of, most had no visible effect. The one thing that seemed to do anything is shown down in the example code below however it overlaps all my links and i do not know how to fix this. Any advice on how to fix this or a better way to do this is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title></title>

        <style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color:green;
    height: 400px;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}

.navbar a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
            <a href="">link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

css is a bit finicky with the positioning.
You first need to give the parent container a position type.
Then the child containers will follow depending on that.

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color:green;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height: 50px;
}

.navbar a {
}
```